# Python type hint when mapping list() to list of strings

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am using map to convert strings to lists:

```
lines = list(map(list, ['abc', 'def']))
assert lines == [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Running mypy on this program gives the following error:

```
test.py:2: error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Type[List[Any]]"; expected "Callable[[str], List[_T]]"
```

What hinting should I do to get rid of this message?

Comment: Using [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast): `lines = list(map(cast(Callable[[str], list[str]], list), ['abc', 'def']))`

Comment: Using list comprehension instead of map + list will also make mypy happy; `lines = [list(x) for x in ['abc', 'def']]`

Comment: This is a known bug in mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9253 . I would go with the list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehension is more pythonic then using map, map is more a functional thing